# Failed to meta-introspect annotation interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-zookeeper, apache-dubbo

**error message**

```
21:13:46,666 DEBUG AnnotationUtils:1889 - Failed to meta-introspect annotation interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.RpcException: No provider available from registry 172.16.33.23:2181 for service com.itheima.service.CheckItemService on consumer 172.16.33.29 use dubbo version 2.6.0, may be providers disabled or not registered ?
at com.alibaba.dubbo.registry.integration.RegistryDirectory.doList(RegistryDirectory.java:572)
```

> I have checked my Dubbo annotation package and controller's import but find that is right.

```
import com.alibaba.dubbo.config.annotation.Reference;
import com.itheima.constant.MessageConstant;
import com.itheima.entity.Result;
import com.itheima.pojo.CheckItem;
import com.itheima.service.CheckItemService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/checkitem")
public class CheckItemController {

    @Reference
    private CheckItemService checkItemService;

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public Result add(@RequestBody CheckItem checkItem){
        try{
            checkItemService.add(checkItem);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new Result(false, MessageConstant.ADD_CHECKITEM_FAIL);
        }
        return  new Result(true, MessageConstant.ADD_CHECKITEM_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Also, my zookeeper started.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./zkServer.sh start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

And the front end request successful.

> it seems that have no problems

```
[zk: 127.0.0.1:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /dubbo/com.itheima.service.CheckItemService
[consumers, configurators, routers, providers]
```

anyone who can give a direction?

> I can almost understand where the mistake is，but I don't know what to do.

[RegisteryDirectoty.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kyXs.png)